# Typeerror: Network Request failed in react-native android

Tags: react-native

[While fetching the API from Rapid API Getting a error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWQ75.png)

[Here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byofY.png)

Comment: first try to run this api on postman or somewhere else and please share complete api response

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it should add method about get or post as parameter?

```
fetch("www.Alice.com.....", {
        "method": "GET",//or POST
        "headers": {
            "x-rapidapi-host": "...",
            "x-rapidapi-key": "..."
        }
    })
```

[React native Networking fetch](https://reactnative.dev/docs/network)

Answer (score 0):

Its saying that the promise isnt handled.. maybe try to put a catch after the 2 then's.

```
.catch(err => console.log(err))
```